# Serious memory leak/zombie event handlers when using `Backbone.history.loadUrl`

Tags: backbone.js, memory-leaks, marionette

In an application, `Backbone.history.loadUrl()` is used to load a page. But I find that events in a view is not unbound, thus creating more and more zombie events when it is used to load a page. Whats the right way of loading a page. (changing URL and probably calling `close()` on active views to trigger any cleanup if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... actually the answer is simple ... I just need to call `.close()` where necessary. In my case:

```
@contentView.close()
Backbone.history.loadUrl Backbone.history.fragment
```